# Unique directory name of mount volume per Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Current docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    dev_service:
        image: my-image
        build: 
            context: .
            target: my-image
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        ports:
            - "6080:80"
            - "6022:22"
        volumes:
            - './workspace/logs:/var/log/peimp'
```

This is fine for a single container instance, but not many.

Logs will be overwritten.

Is there any way to automatically create unique directories that will be shared on the host system?
e.g.

- ./workspace/logs_1,
- ./workspace/logs_2

Comment: Consider setting the process to log to stdout rather than a file, so that `docker logs` can collect that output for you.

Comment: It would be fine to do this, but it's a fairly old project and only file logging is possible

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ENV variable like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    dev_service:
        image: my-image
        build: 
            context: .
            target: my-image
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        ports:
            - "6080:80"
            - "6022:22"
        volumes:
            - './workspace/logs${LOG_NUM}:/var/log/peimp'
```

And then run the docker compose like this:

> export LOG_NUM=1 && docker-compose up